# Why is my pygame window opening and immediately closing?

Tags: python, pygame

Pygame window opens and the closes immediately.

I have copied the code from a youtube channel and it still opens and closes immediately

```
import pygame
pygame.init()



class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.win = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))


    def run(self):
        run = True

        while run:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False

        pygame.quit()


Game = Game()
```

The while loop should be waiting for me to quit but its auto executing the quit function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling using `game = Game()` and then `game.run()`, the code should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your `run` method as follows:

```
game = Game()
game.run()
```